# Castle windsor - null object with Dependecy Injection of class that inherits from a generic base class

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I'm experiencing problems with Castle.Windsor Dependency Injection. 
I'd like to register in the container all my service layer with the related Dao. I'd also like to obtain Propery Injection instead of Constructor injection. When I run the following code I allways find that my Dao objects are null. Certainly I'm doing something wrong with the container registration. I've read and tried many solution I've found on the web without results.

A service Example:

```
public class DummyBLL : IDummyBLL
{
    public IDelegaDao delegaDao { get; set; }
    public IUtenteDao utenteDao { get; set; }
    public IFunzioneDao funzioneDao { get; set; }

    public void dummyMethod(String key)
    { 
    //Business logic that make use of the dao objects
    }
    ...
}
```

Dao Example:

```
public class BaseDao<T> : BaseDao where T : Entita
{
    public BaseDao()
    {
        Session = NHibernateHelper.CurrentSession;
    }

    public BaseDao(ISession session)
    {
        this.Session = session;

    }
}

public class BaseDao 
{
    public ISession Session { get; protected set; }

    public BaseDao()
    {
        SearchFields = new List<string>();
        Session = NHibernateHelper.CurrentSession;

    }

    public BaseDao(ISession session)
    {
        if (session != null)
        {
            Session = session;
        }
        else
        {
            Session = NHibernateHelper.CurrentSession;            
        }

        SearchFields = new List<string>();
    }
}



public interface IFunzioneDao
{
    IEnumerable<COGE.Business.ObjectModel.Funzione> CercaFunzioniPerUtente(Guid idUtente);
    IEnumerable<COGE.Business.Data.Dto.FunzioneDto> GetAllFunzioni();
}

public class FunzioneDao : BaseDao<Funzione>, IFunzioneDao
{
    public FunzioneDao() { }
    public FunzioneDao(ISession session): base(session){}

    public IEnumerable<FunzioneDto> GetAllFunzioni()
    {
        var funzioni = Session.QueryOver<Funzione>()
            .OrderBy(x => x.Categoria).Asc
            .ThenBy(x => x.Descrizione).Asc
            .List();

        return funzioni.Select(x => x.ToDto());
    }   


public class TgcppdcDao : BaseDao, ITgcppdcDao
{
    private IDbConnection connessione = null;
    private ISession session = null;
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(TgcppdcDao));

    public TgcppdcDao()
    {

    }

    public TgcppdcDao(ISession session)
        : base(session)
    {

    }
```

I've some dao that needs to inherit the generic base class and other that needs the non generic one.

To register in the container I'm doing the following:

```
 // service registration              
 container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("COGE.Business").InNamespace("COGE.Business.BLL").WithServiceFirstInterface().LifestyleTransient());

//to register the non generic dao
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("COGE.Business").BasedOn(typeof(BaseDao<>)).WithServiceAllInterfaces().LifestyleTransient());
//to register generic dao
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("COGE.Business").BasedOn(typeof(IBaseGenericDao<>)).WithServiceAllInterfaces().LifestyleTransient());
```

I've no problem with the non generic dao but the injection doesn't work with the generic dao.

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **UPDATE**

Sorry!! I posted a wrong code for the component registration:

       //to register the non generic dao
           container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("COGE.Business").BasedOn(typeof(BaseDao)).WithServiceAllInterfaces().LifestyleTransient());
           //to register generic dao
           container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("COGE.Business").BasedOn(typeof(BaseDao<>)).WithServiceAllInterfaces().LifestyleTransient());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is related to inheritance... "Generic Dao" inherit from "Non generic Dao"... that might(didn't try) create fluent registration confusion...
first registration might register also generic daos due to inheritance...

also be careful to WithServiceAllInterfaces, usually DefaultInterfaces is enough

I rather use a generic interface for all repositories. IRepository where T:Entity: try to implement the repository pattern properly, than you'll register all daos/repositories in one shot

Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("COGE.Business")
.BasedOn(typeof(IRepository<>))
.WithService.DefaultInterfaces().LifestyleTransient()

I don't see the point in your code for generic dao... you are not leveraging generic dao/repository pattern.

Comment: @Giandomenico: now I'm curious... inheritance guess was correct or did you change the approach following repository pattern?

Comment: your hypothesis was right. I Chose to remove the non-generic implementation and this solved the problem. Thanks (sorry if the answer is late)